# Pandas error in python 3.5.1

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, quandl

I am using python 3.5.1,   Following shows data

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl
df = quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')
print(df.head())
```

I am doing following

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl
df = quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')

df = df[['Adj. Open','Adj. High','Adj. Low','Adj. Close','Adj. Volume',]]
df['HL_PCT'] = (df['Adj. High'] - df['Adj. Close']) / df['Adj. Close']*100.0
df['PCT_change'] = (df['Adj. Close'] - df['Adj. Open']) / df['Adj. OPen']*100.0
df = df[['Adj. Close','HL_PCT','PCT_change','Adj. Volume']]

print(df.head())
```

but its showing following error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jayram\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py", line 2134, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 132, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4433)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 154, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4279)
  File "pandas\src\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 732, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:13742)
  File "pandas\src\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 740, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:13696)
KeyError: 'Adj. OPen'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jayram/Desktop/python/ok2", line 7, in 
    df['PCT_change'] = (df['Adj. Close'] - df['Adj. Open']) / df['Adj. OPen']*100.0
  File "C:\Users\jayram\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2059, in **getitem**
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "C:\Users\jayram\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2066, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "C:\Users\jayram\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1386, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "C:\Users\jayram\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3543, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "C:\Users\jayram\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py", line 2136, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 132, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4433)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 154, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4279)
  File "pandas\src\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 732, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:13742)
  File "pandas\src\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 740, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:13696)
KeyError: 'Adj. OPen'

Process finished with exit code 1

how to solve above error

Comment: Try to change: `df['Adj. Open']) / df['Adj. OPen']` --> `df['Adj. Open']) / df['Adj. Open']`

Comment: yes works, was small mistake

Answer (score 1):

change

```
df['PCT_change'] = (df['Adj. Close'] - df['Adj. Open']) / df['Adj. OPen']*100.0
```

to

```
df['PCT_change'] = (df['Adj. Close'] - df['Adj. Open']) / df['Adj. Open']*100.0
```

Comment: This would be better as a comment to the OP, as there is little long term value to the OP staying on SO since it is simply a typo.